# Is there a way to add circles on the border of a marker icon and end the polyline there in leaflet JS?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have added a few icon markers on leaflet JS. These are mostly square and circle icons.
And I'm drawing a polyline to connect these icons on selection. The issue is, the polyline appears to extend beyond the icon to the actual point.

What I'm looking for is something like this:

[image]

Would it be possible to add these circles on the icon border and start/end the polyline there?